# Multitasking bar does not show up on my iPhone

Tags: ios, multitasking

The following page indicates what the multitasking bar should look like after pressing home twice:

https://gigaom.com/2011/02/21/ios-101-how-to-use-multitasking-on-your-iphone-or-ipad/

[image]

However when I press home twice instead the running apps are shown in the deck of cards - and *nothing* is shown at the bottom of the screen.

This is on an iPhone 5c with iOS 10.3.3. What should I do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple changed how multitasking looks and works with the release of iOS 7 in 2013, from the ‘bar’ to the cards layout. The cards are previews of the apps represented by the icons in the picture you provided. It is not possible to achieve the picture in modern iOS without jailbreaking.

Comment: How to do the following with the cards:  (from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5159273?start=0&tstart=0) : `When multitasking bar appears, click and hold on messages icon till red x appears. Click red x to get rid of icon. Go back to message and screen flips now`

Comment: Swipe the card up

Comment: I do not follow. The only thing that swiping up can do afaict is allow "closing" an app. There are no additional buttons etc available.

Comment: Right, because they changed it. It does the same thing